# Centering text and image together in React app

Tags: html, css

I have a logo and some text I would like to center together on the same line. Currently they are on the left side of the page but not sure how to go about this. I have both the image and text in a div. The css I used doesn't seem to work. the .logo_and_text is the class for both items
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to align the items in the center of the div, use `align-items: center`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, if that's what you meant by "centered on the same line"

```
.logo_and_text {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

-- edit -----

Add `justify-content: center;` to center them horizontally. To have the image on the left, either change your html elements, or add some css like this:

```
.logo_and_text h3 { order: 2; }
.logo_and_text img { order: 1; }
```

Comment: I did it and they are together but now the way I want it, I want the logo on the left side and the text on the right side and to be in the middle of the page. They are both still on the left side. Do I have to add styling to them in separate classes to make that possible?

Comment: Add `justify-content: center` to center them horizontally.
To have the image on the left, either change your html elements, or add some css like this: ```.logo_and_text h3 { order: 2; }
.logo_and_text img { order: 1; }```